# I can move text 50px from left

Tags: html, css

I have navigation bar. I want to move the text 50px from left. I can do this?

```
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height:35px;
  background-color: #f1b500; /*f2c255*/
  margin-top: 4.4em;
}

.navigation a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.navigation .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1b500;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 9px rbga(0,0,0,0.2)
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: inherit;
}

.navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #34b0ff;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #34b0ff;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

The menu text is now all the way to the left. I would like to move it 50 pixels further to the right. Is the code wrong or do you just need to add something? I tried adding margin-left: 50px; but it does not work. I state that I am a beginner on programming.

---

```
<div class="navigation" id="Nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropbutton
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
      <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

This is my html code. I forgot to post it

Comment: *I want to move the text 50px from left.* Where is your HTML that you want to move ? You have CSS only in question.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `float` unless you have a good reason. There's margin, padding, and text-indent which can move text for you. Need a reproducible example to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding-left:50px to .navigation. and everything will move to the right 50px

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height:35px;
  background-color: #f1b500; /*f2c255*/
  margin-top: 4.4em;
  padding-left:50px;
}

.navigation a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.navigation .icon {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 25px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1b500;
    min-width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 9px rbga(0,0,0,0.2)
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: inherit;
}

.navigation a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #34b0ff;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #34b0ff;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation" id="Nav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropbutton
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
      <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: But it's wrong because I want the navigation menu to be moved 50px further to the right.

Comment: you wnat whole navigation menu to be to the right ..?

Comment: try this new code. i think this will help you. i edited my previous code

Comment: It's my solution. Thank you. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

yeah change your padding to `8px 25px 0px 50px`

Comment: Most style guides for CSS will point out that `0px` is better expressed as just `0`. Given that there is more than one place in the example where padding appears it might be worth pointing out which place you intended this change to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Either adding `padding-left: 50px;` or `transform: translateY(50px);`